# Report Formula on Bucket Field

Tags: reporting, formula, custom-report-type, bucket

I am tried to use a custom Bucket Field that denotes the won and lost Opportunities in a report formula, but I am having issues with the correct syntax. The end result would display % of won/lost opportunities on the `Calendar_Month(CloseDate)` grouping level.

Any help would be much appreciated.

This is my current report setup:

[image]

This is the formula

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, as we need to display the Win/Lost ratio for each calendar month the summary levels should be calculated as Close Date and Column Grand Summary. So that, PARENTGROUPVAL function will give count of total/won records for particular month. As Won/Lost ratio should be displayed which is count of won records by Total records in a month. So the formula should be as follows.

[image]